# How do I install Intel's ifortran and MKLs on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, open-source

I need to install Intel's ifortran and Math Kernel Libraries (MKL) on OS X 10.7 Lion, [available (for non-commercial use) here](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/RegCenter/AutoGen.aspx?ProductID=1523&AccountID=&EmailID=&ProgramID=&RequestDt=&rm=NCOM&lang=). Has anyone experience in doing so? Or should I rather setup a virtual Linux instead?

Comment: @Mark the answer below (use Linux) is more or less the last resort to take if you really want to have ifort on OS X, and since I´m still trying to get it running on my Mac, I´m waiting until I know it´s the only option (and correct answer).

Comment: Linux and OSX have totally different object structures so you can't run code from one on the other without some emulation layer.

Answer (score 1):

The [non commercial tools](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-download/) all appear to be for Linux ony so you will need to use the VM.

Although [TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/download.php) is available for OS X.